# Create New Health State in SCOM

Tags: scom, system-center

We have three health states in SCOM - Healthy, Warning and Critical. Is it possible to add a new custom health state? I tried by editing the System.Health.Library but failed. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no other answer except "No. It's impossible.". SCOM has three states maximum hardcoded in a lot of places and it doesn't allow you to have 4 states or more. It's really weird because 4+ states can bring us a lot of interesting and valuable scenarios (especially for ITSM integration), but it is what it is.
I recommend you think how you can break your monitor down to 2 or more monitors to have reasonable and clear 2 or 3-state monitors. In major cases it's possible. If you can give me more details about your case - I'll be glad to help you with design.

Good luck!
Roman.

Comment: We already have boiled it down to three states. I am just wondering if I can do so. The customer would really be happy to see all the available states.